# Auto Refresh Div container

Tags: javascript, html

I have function like:
`document.getElementById("IR_0_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["IR_0"];`

and i get this info like: `h2 id="IR_0_ph" class="number">0</h2>`
All work fine, but he not auto update info, if i manual reloat page all its good, but i need auto update this info.
mb i can refresh just main Div Container or .... ?

```js
function data_handler(sent_dict) {
  socket.emit("control_event", {
    data: "Hello!"
  }); // tell the RPI that the wifi connection is still working
  
  document.getElementById("IR_0_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["IR_0"];
  document.getElementById("IR_1_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["IR_1"];
  document.getElementById("IR_4_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["IR_4"];
  document.getElementById("IR_Yaw_right_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["IR_Yaw_right"];
  document.getElementById("IR_Yaw_left_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["IR_Yaw_left"];
  document.getElementById("Yaw_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["Yaw"];
  document.getElementById("p_part_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["p_part"];
  document.getElementById("alpha_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["alpha"];
  document.getElementById("Kp_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["Kp"];
  document.getElementById("Kd_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["Kd"];
  document.getElementById("blue_percentage_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["blue_percentage"];

  stored_state = document.getElementById("state_table_1_ph").innerHTML;
  new_state = sent_dict["AUTO_STATE"];
  if (new_state != stored_state) {
    insert_into_state_table_ph(new_state);
  }

  document.getElementById("manual_state_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["manual_state"];
  document.getElementById("mode_ph").innerHTML = sent_dict["mode"];
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="statistic__item">
        <h2 id="IR_0_ph" class="number">unknown</h2>
        <span class="desc">FRONT SIDE</span>
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-o"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code by itself works. Your error is in code you haven't posted. Also camelcase is used in Javascript (`dataHandler`) and kebab case in css (`IR-0-ph`). This doesn update the tag:

`const testData = { IR_0: 'TEST!' }

function data_handler(sent_dict) {
  document.getElementById('IR_0_ph').innerHTML = sent_dict.IR_0;
}

data_handler(testData)`

Answer (score 0):

1) How data_handler function being called from what way, is it called from some async flow or its just a one time calling function.

2) Where the sent_dict is coming from ?

Not sure How you are calling, and how sent_dict data passing to dataHandler function. Assuming sent_dict is a server call or device response.

There are two use cases or senarios:

1) calling once.
    example:

```
   ajaxCall.then(sent_dict =>   data_handler(sent_dict));
```

if yes, perform the ajax call in intervals using setTimeout function of javascript.
       setTimeout(ajaxCall, interval_time).
     or you can use observable interval operator to mimic the same behavior without doing much. which will automatically update the div on each time response gets from server.

2) if it is calling more than once or interval based calling.
       following code in not enough to answer your question.